# c++ for loop converted to a while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

Hi I wrote this code to print out factors of an integer with a for looop

how do i write it with a while loop?

```
for(int i = 1; i <  integer+1; i++)
{
    if(integer % i == 0)
        cout<< i<<" ";
}
```

Comment: You culd just stop at `integer / 2` since numbers that large will obviously not divide evenly into it.  How about you try it first and see if you can figure it out?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/

Comment: Which part of the task are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Ed S.: you forgot about `integer`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: ...ok, that's true, but you can always just assume that N is divisible by N.  My point is that running the loop on values greater than `(n / 2) + 1` is a waste of time.

Comment: @Ed S.: actually sqrt(n) is enough because they come in pairs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int i = 1;
while (i < integer+1)
{
  if(integer % i == 0)
    cout<< i<<" ";
  i++;
}
```

Or even better:

```
int i = 0;
while (++i < integer+1)
{
  if(integer % i == 0)
    cout<< i<<" ";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int i = 1;
while(i < integer + 1) {
    // your current loop body goes here
    i++;
}
```

See [equivalent forms of for loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#Equivalence_with_while_loops).

Answer (score 0):

Following code will print the same result as your for loop in printing.

```
 int i = 1;
    while(i < integer + 1)
    {
        if(integer % i == 0)
         {   cout<< i<<" "; }
         i++;

    }
```