# How can use css in jquery when shuffling a drag and drop

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made a "choose and reorder" module in which we drag and drop the options if the options are arranged in correct order then it will show button along with it that this is correct(shown in the figure) https://www.screencast.com/t/n8u5M0akkJd

I have made two button review or correct answer for showing correct sequence or correct answer but my button can not fix after review my answer

```js
function shuffle(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        let temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
let question = {
    name: "Sort",
    options: ["A sentence is a set of words that in principle tells a complete thought,", "although it may make little sense taken in isolation out of context.", "Typically a sentence contains a subject and predicate."],
    correctSeq: "1,2,3"
};
let is_answer_correct = false;
let correct_html = "";
let current_html = "";

function init() {
    let list_html = [];
    let li_class = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
    for (let i = 0; i < question.options.length; i++) {
        let li_html = '<li class="ui_color" id="item_' + i + '" cseq="' + i + '" useq=""><a class="' + li_class[i] + '"><span class="number"></span>' + question.options[i] + '</a></li>';
        list_html.push(li_html);
    }
    correct_html = createHTML(list_html, false);
    createHTML(list_html, true);
}
function createHTML(list_html, is_shuffle) {
    $('.header').find('span').text(question.name);
    if (is_shuffle) {
        var list_html = shuffle(list_html);
    }
    let list_html_str = list_html.join('');
    if (is_shuffle) {
        $('ul').append(list_html_str);
    } else {
        return list_html_str;
    }
}
$(function() {
    init();
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        revert: true
    });
    $("#draggable").draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#sortable",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid"
    });
    $("ul,li").disableSelection();
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        revert: true,
        update: function(event, ui) {
            let x = evalAns();
        }
    });

});
function evalAns() {
    let seq = 0;
    $(".ui_color").each(function() {
        $(this).attr('useq', seq);
        seq++;
        $(this).find('.number').html(+$(this).attr('useq') + 1);
        let is_correct = $(this).attr('useq') == $(this).attr('cseq');
        is_answer_correct = is_correct;
    });
}
function reviewAnswer(is_correct) {
    let btnui = {
        incorrecet: ['wrong', 'Wrong'],
        correct: ['right', 'Correct']
    };
    console.log(btnui);
    if (typeof is_correct == 'undefined' && $('#review').attr('correct') == 1) {
        $('ul').html(current_html);
        $('#review').attr('correct', 0);
        console.log(review);
    }
    $(".ui_color").each(function() {
        let is_correct = $(this).attr('useq') == $(this).attr('cseq');
        let btn_css = is_correct ? btnui.correct : btnui.incorrecet;
        $(this).find('button').remove();
        $(this).append('<button type="button" class="' + btn_css[0] + '">' + btn_css[1] + '</button>');
    });
    let is_correct_ans = is_correct || is_answer_correct;
    let res_ui = is_correct_ans ? btnui.correct : btnui.incorrecet;
 $('.first_right').html('').append('<button type="button" class="' + res_ui[0] + '">' + res_ui[1] + '</button>')
 $('.result').html('').append('<button type="button" class="' + res_ui[0] + '">' + res_ui[1] + '</button>') 
 $('.third_result').html('').append('<button type="button" class="' + res_ui[0] + '">' + res_ui[1] + '</button>')
 }

function correctAnswer() {
    current_html = $('ul').html();
    $('ul').html(correct_html);
    $(".ui_color").each(function() {
        $(this).attr('useq', $(this).attr('cseq'));
    });
    $('#review').attr('correct', 1);
    reviewAnswer(true);
}
```

```css
ul { 
    list-style-type: none; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
 }
.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.result
{
 position: relative;
    bottom: 5em;
    left: 14em;
}
.ui_color { 
    margin: 5px; 
    padding: 5px; 
    width: 570px; 
    height: 47px;
    background-color: #46B8DA;
    border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #454545;
}
.header
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 569px;
    height: 37px;
    padding: 17px 0 0 11px;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
.bottom{
    display: inline;
    float: none;
    padding: 0px 6px 1px 6px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 7em;
    left: 14em;
}
.tablelike
{
 height: 368px;
}
.full_border
{
    border: 1px solid #800080;
    width: 592px;
}
.first_right
{
 background: #008000;
    position: relative;
    left: 55%;
    top: 7px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #008000;
    width: 90px;
    height: 31px;
 box-shadow: 3px 6px 5px #888888;
}
.third_right
{ 
 background: #008000;
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    bottom: 7px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #008000;
    width: 90px;
    height: 31px;
 box-shadow: 3px 6px 5px #888888;
}
.right {
 background: #008000;
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    top: 7px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #008000;
    width: 90px;
    height: 31px;
 box-shadow: 3px 6px 5px #888888;
}
.wrong{
 background: #b20000;
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    top: 7px;
 border: 1px solid #b20000;
 width: 90px;
    height: 31px;
    color: #fff;
 box-shadow: 3px 6px 5px #888888;
}
.first
{
 padding: 0px 115px 0px 0px;
}
.second
{
 padding: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>jQuery UI Draggable + Sortable</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="jq.css" type="text/css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="jq_assingment.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
 <form name="drag_drop" id="drag_drop" class="full_border">
  <div class="header">
   <span id="draggable" class="border">Choose & Re-order</span>
  </div>
  <div>   
   <ul id="sortable" class="tablelike">
   </ul>
  </div>  
  <div class="result">
  </div>
  <div>
   <button type="button" onclick="reviewAnswer()" correct="0" id="review">Review</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="correctAnswer()">Correct answer</button>
  </div>
  <div id="demo"></div>
 </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

. when I applying CSS but is not working. Kindly suggest me what can I do 
[image: This image is example of my page]

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is useful for you.

```js
function shuffle(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        let temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
let question = {
    name: "Sort",
    options: ["A sentence is a set of words that in principle tells a complete thought,", "although it may make little sense taken in isolation out of context.", "Typically a sentence contains a subject and predicate."],
    correctSeq: "1,2,3"
};
let is_answer_correct = false;
let correct_html = "";
let current_html = "";

function init() {
    let list_html = [];
    let li_class = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
    for (let i = 0; i < question.options.length; i++) {
        let li_html = '<li class="ui_color" id="item_' + i + '" cseq="' + i + '" useq=""><a class="' + li_class[i] + '"><span class="number"></span>' + question.options[i] + '</a></li>';
        list_html.push(li_html);
    }
    correct_html = createHTML(list_html, false);
    createHTML(list_html, true);
}
function createHTML(list_html, is_shuffle) {
    $('.header').find('span').text(question.name);
    if (is_shuffle) {
        var list_html = shuffle(list_html);
    }
    let list_html_str = list_html.join('');
    if (is_shuffle) {
        $('ul').append(list_html_str);
    } else {
        return list_html_str;
    }
}
$(function() {
    init();
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        revert: true
    });
    $("#draggable").draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#sortable",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid"
    });
    $("ul,li").disableSelection();
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        revert: true,
        update: function(event, ui) {
            let x = evalAns();
        }
    });

});
function evalAns() {
    let seq = 0;
    $(".ui_color").each(function() {
        $(this).attr('useq', seq);
        seq++;
        $(this).find('.number').html(+$(this).attr('useq') + 1);
        let is_correct = $(this).attr('useq') == $(this).attr('cseq');
        is_answer_correct = is_correct;
    });
}
function reviewAnswer(is_correct) {
    let btnui = {
        incorrecet: ['wrong', 'Wrong'],
        correct: ['right', 'Correct']
    };
    console.log(btnui);
    if (typeof is_correct == 'undefined' && $('#review').attr('correct') == 1) {
        $('ul').html(current_html);
        $('#review').attr('correct', 0);
        console.log(review);
    }
    $(".ui_color").each(function() {
        let is_correct = $(this).attr('useq') == $(this).attr('cseq');
        let btn_css = is_correct ? btnui.correct : btnui.incorrecet;
        $(this).find('button').remove();
        $(this).append('<button type="button" class="' + btn_css[0] + '">' + btn_css[1] + '</button>');
    });
    let is_correct_ans = is_correct || is_answer_correct;
    let res_ui = is_correct_ans ? btnui.correct : btnui.incorrecet;
 $('.first_right').html('').append('<button type="button" class="' + res_ui[0] + '">' + res_ui[1] + '</button>')
 $('.result').html('').append('<button type="button" class="' + res_ui[0] + '">' + res_ui[1] + '</button>') 
 $('.third_result').html('').append('<button type="button" class="' + res_ui[0] + '">' + res_ui[1] + '</button>')
 }

function correctAnswer() {
    current_html = $('ul').html();
    $('ul').html(correct_html);
    $(".ui_color").each(function() {
        $(this).attr('useq', $(this).attr('cseq'));
    });
    $('#review').attr('correct', 1);
    reviewAnswer(true);
}
```

```css
ul { 
  list-style-type: none; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px; 
 }
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.result{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5em;
  left: 14em;
}
.ui_color { 
  margin: 5px; 
  padding: 5px; 
  width: 570px; 
  height: 47px;
  background-color: #46B8DA;
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #454545;
  position:relative;
}
.header{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 569px;
  height: 37px;
  padding: 17px 0 0 11px;
  margin-left: 6px;
}
.bottom{
  display: inline;
  float: none;
  padding: 0px 6px 1px 6px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 7em;
  left: 14em;
}
.tablelike{
  height: 368px;
}
.full_border{
  border: 1px solid #800080;
  width: 592px;
}
.first_right{
  background: #008000;
  position: relative;
  left: 55%;
  top: 7px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #008000;
  width: 90px;
  height: 31px;
  box-shadow: 3px 6px 5px #888888;
}
.third_right{ 
  background: #008000;
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  bottom: 7px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #008000;
  width: 90px;
  height: 31px;
  box-shadow: 3px 6px 5px #888888;
}
.right {
  background: #008000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 7px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #008000;
  width: 90px;
  height: 31px;
  box-shadow: 3px 6px 5px #888888;
}
.wrong{
  background: #b20000;
  position: relative;
  right: 20px;
  top: 7px;
  border: 1px solid #b20000;
  width: 90px;
  height: 31px;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 3px 6px 5px #888888;
  position:absolute;
}
.ui_color a {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 79%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.result .wrong , .result .right{
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>jQuery UI Draggable + Sortable</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="jq.css" type="text/css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="jq_assingment.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
 <form name="drag_drop" id="drag_drop" class="full_border">
  <div class="header">
    <span id="draggable" class="border">Choose & Re-order</span>
  </div>
  <div>   
    <ul id="sortable" class="tablelike">
    </ul>
  </div>  
  <div class="result">
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="reviewAnswer()" correct="0" id="review">Review</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="correctAnswer()">Correct answer</button>
  </div>
  <div id="demo"></div>
 </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: where you want to put third button..?

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/n8u5M0akkJd 
Like this i want in both wrong and right button

Comment: what is my mistake can you explain

Comment: @ankitapatel You just copied my solution and you also set in class wrong, position absolute and relative.... Punit your mistake was you set the class wrong and right to relative, you should have gone for position absolute instead and you set it to left: 20 px; instead of right: 20px;

Comment: @Doomenik I am not copied your code. I give proper solution and your solution is not proper please check your solution first.

Comment: @Doomenik till now your result button position is not proper in your solution.

Comment: This is only cause I did not know, there he want the fourth button until now, and @ankitapatel the rest of your code is just the same like mine :) But what ever

Comment: @ankitapatel Also you multiple set css values which is completly the worst practice at all. `.result .wrong , .result .right{
  position: relative;`  Alone this line is very bad practice, cause you override it anyway ..

Comment: @Doomenik this is not worst i give both because both button class is generated different

Comment: @ankitapatel and why you give the class wrong `position: relative; and position: absolute;` in the same class declaration ? Anyway your solution works its just bad practice.

Comment: @ankitpatel can we change loop in my code i am using while

Comment: @punitsaharawat yes you can and if you have any problem in css then inform me.

Comment: how can i change any idea?

Comment: @punitsaharawat pls see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795898/c-for-loop-converted-to-a-while-loop. I think this link is helpful for you.

Comment: @ankitpatel how can give some space between number or text in li.??

Comment: @punitsaharawat pls provide some example how you want..?

Comment: @ankitpatel  like this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153220/discussion-between-ankita-patel-and-punit-saharawat).

Comment: @punitsaharawat pls add this style `padding-left:10px` in this class `.ui_color a`.

Comment: hello @ankitpatel I have problem in css kindly help me

Comment: pls raise question in stack overflow and i will solve it.

Comment: Hello @ankita i placed a query kindly look in to this.

Comment: Kindly check can we start conversation with help of chat