# C++ For to While Loop

Tags: c++

I was wondering whether it is possible to change the **FOR** loops to **WHILE** loops using C++.

Here is part of the code below.

```
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
    sum = sum + MyList[i]; 
}

cout << "The Total is: " << 
sum <<endl; int largest = MyList[0]; 

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    if ( MyList[i] > largest ) 
        cout << "The Largest Value is: " << largest <<endl; 

int smallest = MyList[0];

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    if ( MyList[i] < smallest ) smallest = MyList[I];
cout << "the Smallest Value is: " << smallest <<endl;
```

Comment: yes, that is possible - but why?

Comment: While this is possible, I do not see a point in that. This for loop `for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)` is pretty basic and easier to read then a while loop.

Comment: @luk2302 To show that using a  different algorithm is possible.

Comment: Work on your indentation-skill first, to make that piece of code readable. Then think about if you really need the for to while conversion.

Comment: And no, turning a for loop into a while loop doesn't really change the algorithm, it just make it *look* a little different.

Comment: @TobiasWeimer I know you may not see the point changing it from a for to while loop, but it is to demonstrate it can be done.

Comment: Almost everyone already *knows* it can be done. We just don't see the point in doing that, because it doesn't really change anything. And there are several thousands (if not tens of thousands) of examples all over the Internet, and in many good books as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There is nothing wrong with my 'indentation skill' - It is the way stackoverflow formatted it.

Comment: Do you understand the difference in your case? (switching to `while` loop, you need to assign and increment the loop variable `i`) .. then you would realize why this is a basic loop that _need not_ be a `while` loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ for loop converted to a while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795898/c-for-loop-converted-to-a-while-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int sum = 0;
int i = 0;
while (i < length ) { 
    sum = sum + MyList[i]; 
i++;
}

cout << "The Total is: " <<sum <<endl; 
int largest = MyList[0]; 
i = 0; 
while (i < length) 
   { if ( MyList[i] > largest ) 
        cout << "The Largest Value is: " << largest <<endl; 
 i++;
}

int smallest = MyList[0];
 i = 0;
while ( i < length) 
    {
if ( MyList[i] < smallest ) smallest = MyList[I];
i++;
  }
cout << "the Smallest Value is: " << smallest <<endl;
```

1. your code of for loop will look like this when converted to while loop.
2. In case of "for" loop we initialize, check condition and increment/decrement while passing parameters. Where as in case of "while"loop we initialize first and then  pass the condition as parameter
   and when loop is about to repeat we increment/decrement

Comment: This very much risks misuse of `i`. It is only a matter of when you will forget to reset `i` between loops.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (beginning; condition; increment) { 
    body; 
}
```

is equivalent to

```
{
    beginning; 
    while (condition) { 
        body; 
        increment; 
    }
}
```

There is not much more to demonstrate.

Comment: You forget an important part: The whole thing needs to be put into a new block scope, so nested withing `{` and `}`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks, you are referring to variables defined inside `beginning` not being "available" outside of the block?